# Trouble connecting to web3 1.0 through web browser using Infura.io

Tags: web3js, addresses, infura, balances

I am trying to connect to web3 1.0 through a web browser, I dont see much documentation for 1.0 though. This script says im connected but I think its the previous version as anytime I try and run a 1.0 function I get the function is undefined -

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

<script>

function initweb3 () {
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/My Api Key"));        
}

window.addEventListener('load',initweb3);

if(web3.isConnected()) {
    alert("Web3 Connected!");
} else {
    alert("Web3 Not Conected");
}

var abi = JSON.parse('[{"MY ABI"}]')

var AK = new web3.eth.contract(abi);

// Set Contract Address
AK.options.address = "Contract Address";

AK.methods.balanceOf("Address to get balance of").call().then(function(balance) { 
alert("Balance is " + balance.toString()) });
```

This Throws

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'address' of undefined
```

It works fine when I run locally so I think its not connecting to version 1.0

Answer (score 1):

I see that you found out a solution apparently. However the code proposed in the description of the problem is not correct and could have led to your error:

```
var AK = new web3.eth.contract(...)
```

Should actually be

```
var AK = new web3.eth.Contract(...)
```

Note the uppercase, which is necessary since you're actually instanciating a class here. This could have led to the `undefined` issue you faced. Furthermore, you can simplify your code (remove one line) by loading the contract at address directly:

```
var AK = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, address)
```

This saves you one line. See the [full documentation here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html).

Comment: yes you are correct, the lower case was for the older version and uppercase is needed for 1.0, I fixed this in my script but forgot to update it here.. Great catch!

Answer (score 0):

It works now

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

```
var web3 = new Web3();
if(web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MY API KEY'))){
web3.eth.net.isListening();
}
```